# elasticsearch filter by several conditions applied on array elements

Tags: elasticsearch

Each of my documents contain an array like

```
"idList": [
'DCCA7703Orange shirt',
'EFBA6705Blue bag',
'O7BA6405Blue socks'
]
```

I want to write a query to get only the documents where one or more of the elements of the "idList" array satisfy two conditions: that the value starts with one parameter and contains a second value parameter, all on the same element. For instance applying the logic to the example document above, if the parameters were "EFBA6705" and "bag" then it would be a hit, but not if the parameters were "EFBA6705" and "socks" since they are indeed in the array but on two different elements. This array is a property of type "text", I do not have control over the mappings of the document, so I cannot convert it to a "nested" type or any other type.

```
 "idList": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
}
```

My elastic search version is 5.6.11.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing mapping [Wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) can work in this case

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "idList.keyword": {
        "value": "EFBA6705* bag"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: field name should be `idList.keyword` and it will work.

Comment: I did try this but it wouldn't work.. I did manage though to change the mapping (I thought I wasn't going to be able to but I did) and upon changing the mapping type to just "Keyword" it worked. Thanks!